# Why did St Augustine think that the first even number was 4?

Tags: math-history

Just wondering what the criteria for a 'whole even number' was?

"Suffice it here to say, that three is the first whole number that is odd, four the first that is even, and of these two, seven is composed."

-St Augustine, City of God , ~Pg 475

> [image: Text excerpt]

Comment: Have been told this 

"read nichomachus and iamblichus; 1 was never considered a number in antiquity, and 2 was not considered a number during late antiquity. rather they were seen as engendering principles from which the series of number and their corresponding species were derived."

Comment: I suspect that this is a better fit for the [History of Math and Science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: Apologies I didnt know that even existed

Comment: Following @Mr_Bodger's comemnt, for Ancient Greeks a *number* is a [plurality composed of *units*](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/bookVII.html#defs). This, the unit $1$ is not a number, properly speaking.

Comment: An [*even* number](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/defVII6.html) "is that which is divisible into two equal parts." Thus, if we follow the above reasoning, the numebr *two* is not composed of two equal numbers, because *one* is not a number. The first *even* will be $4=2+2$.

Comment: An [*odd* number](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/defVII6.html) is defined as "that which is not divisible into two equal parts, or that which differs by a unit from an even number." Thus, $3=2+1$ is odd.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Don't you mean $3=4-1$ in your last comment, as $2$ isn't an even number?